# WPF Flowdocument - Prevent line break before % sign

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I've got a FlowDocument generating a document for a client, and it's getting a line break that they don't like.  Is there any way to mark a section of text that it should avoid line breaks?  Something like this:

```
<Paragraph>Here is a paragraph where there should be <span NoLineBreak=True>no line break</span> in a certain part.</Paragraph>
```

Obviously, a Span doesn't have a NoLineBreak property, but I'm wondering if there's some equivilant functionality available, or if someone can get me started on a way of implementing a SpanWithNoLineBreak class or RunWithNoLineBreak class?

**UPDATE**
Actually, one issue I'm having is with a percent sign, where there isn't even a space:

```
<Paragraph>When I print and &#x00BD;% I want the one-half and '%' symbols to not line break between them.</Paragraph>
```

The & #x00BD; is the unicode for a ½ symbol.  I'm getting a line wrap between the 1/2 and the % even though there's no space between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unicode character "Word Joiner" ([U+2060](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm)) is intended for just this purpose. It "does not normally produce any space but prohibits a line break on either side of it" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)). You place it between U+00BD and '%' to prevent a line break between them.

Unfortunately, WPF (or perhaps the typical fonts supplied with Windows) don't support it properly, and instead render it as a square box. As an alternative, you could use U+FEFF; the use of this character as a zero-width non-breaking space is now deprecated (it's reserved for use as a byte-order mark), but it worked as a line-break-preventer for me.

Finally, there are some other characters that can also be used for this purpose: [U+202F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202F/index.htm) (narrow no-break space) also prevents breaking, but also renders as a very thin space. [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) (no-break space) prevents breaking and displays as a normal space.

Comment: Looks very promising -- I'll be able to try this out tomorrow

Comment: Perfect!  The U+2060 actually seemed to work for me, and survived a conversion to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the spaces with [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

**EDIT**: Well there's always the backup plan of just putting in TextBlocks in your FlowDocument with TextWrapping=NoWrap, but I'd try to find a better way...

Comment: Sorry, I clipped too much out of my scenario trying to simplify the problem.  I've updated the question.  I don't actually have spaces in the part of the document that's line-wrapping.